# I changed the display name of my app in xcode and it no longer runs without crashing

Tags: ios, xcode

After I tried changing the display name of the project, whenever I run it, as it launches it crashes with this error message:

> 2020-03-23 19:32:05.010069+0200 Coronavirus Tool[10927:4335736]
>   Unknown class _TtC8CoronaMT18TipsViewController in Interface Builder
>   file. 2020-03-23 19:32:05.059007+0200 Coronavirus Tool[10927:4335736]
>   Unknown class _TtC8CoronaMT24StatisticsViewController in Interface
>   Builder file. 2020-03-23 19:32:05.061510+0200 Coronavirus
>   Tool[10927:4335736] Unknown class
>   _TtC8CoronaMT28RiskCalculatorViewController in Interface Builder file. 2020-03-23 19:32:05.063672+0200 Coronavirus Tool[10927:4335736]
>   Unknown class _TtC8CoronaMT27NotificationsViewController in Interface
>   Builder file. 2020-03-23 19:32:05.067168+0200 Coronavirus
>   Tool[10927:4335736] Unknown class _TtC8CoronaMT18MoreViewController in
>   Interface Builder file. 2020-03-23 19:32:05.131735+0200 Coronavirus
>   Tool[10927:4335736] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: ‘[<UIViewController 0x101c0e820>
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key blueButton.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x181086d8c 0x1802405ec 0x1810869f0 0x1819dc44c 0x18b1375a0 0x18b3097e4 0x180f94b24 0x18b3081f4
>   0x18b139aa8 0x18ad7d074 0x18aca1b14 0x18ad4fe1c 0x18ad4f2d8
>   0x18ad4ec14 0x18ad4e6a4 0x18ad423a8 0x18ac9a6f4 0x18520fe54
>   0x185213fe4 0x1851806c8 0x1851a81b0 0x18b084680 0x18102f2bc
>   0x18102ea7c 0x18102c7b0 0x180f4cda8 0x182f32020 0x18af6c758
>   0x100bc550c 0x1809ddfc0) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught
>   exception of type NSException

I've tried adding the Bundle display name in the info.plist, and reverting the name back to the way it was, along with cleaning the project, restarting xcode, and deleting the app/reinstalling it.

Can someone please help me fix this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the “UIViewController ... is not KVC-compliant for ...” message is an indication that the base class for your scene has not been set (hence the “UIViewController” at the start of the warning), and therefore the `blueButton` outlet wasn’t found.

(FWIW, if the warning was “RiskCalculatorViewController ... is not KVC-compliant for ...”, that would suggest a problem with the outlet in that particular `UIViewController` subclass. But the error doesn’t reference any particular subclass of `UIViewController`, which indicates that the problem is not the outlet itself, but rather with the base class of this storyboard scene.)

Fortunately, you shared a series of error messages with us. We can see a litany of view controller classes that the storyboard was unable to find (see the errors before the bolded one). This suggest a more fundamental problem, where something went wrong in your renaming process, rendering all of these storyboard base classes unfindable.

If you can, rollback to prior version of the app and try the renaming process again.

If not, you’ll have to manually clean this up. It seems that at least one of two possibilities has taken place:

1. Your view controller classes (and possibly other source files) do not have not their “Target Membership” set correctly:

   [image]

   Make sure you have a checkmark next to your main target.
2. Assuming that’s OK/fixed, go back to your storyboard and check the “Module” selected for your scene’s base class.

   [image]

   Make sure the “Module” is your main target.

   Sometimes you can just select the module and you’ll be fine. Sometimes, though, this doesn’t work. In that case, I often will delete the “Class” name in this “Custom Class” section, leave the field, and then come back and enter the class name again, and the module will be selected correctly.

Comment: The issue was that the module seemed to be wrong! There was a dropdown list that contained the newer-named module, so I selected that and it ran successfully! Just to note as well, I had to do this process for each of my view controllers to prevent crashing once they were opened, including a prototype UITableViewCell. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your clue in this error is `blueButton`. My hunch is that the IBOutlet has a previous outlet still connected to `blueButton`. Check to see if you have two outlets connected to `blueButton`. If so, Xcode crashes because it doesn't know which outlet to use. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, from what I can see by looking at the outlets in the storyboard, it only seems to have one. I'm also still pretty sure that this has to do with changing the display name, as before the name change, everything was running fine, and after the name change this error occurred. In between those two runs, I didn't make any changes to the files related to blueButton. In addition, I got the same error earlier by changing the name, which I was able to fix by adding Bundle display name to the info.plist. However, this hasn't been working this time around.

Comment: I know this may be a silly question but did you change the display name back to its original name? Are your still getting the same error? If so, you should also check on your View Controller and make sure it's using the proper UIViewController class.

Comment: Are you using Storyboard or XIB in the view controller that is using the `blueButton`?

Comment: I tried changing the display name back to the original name, and it still produced the same error. The view controller is using the proper UIViewController class, and I'm using storyboard for the view controller.